# Naming.lookup fails with Java WebStart

Tags: java, java-web-start, jrmp

I have a Java application which I am in the process of converting to work with WebStart.  It is supposed to connect to a server to do some authentication using Naming.lookup and this works fine when running as a standalone app.  Unfortunately when running the same code as a WebStart app the call fails and throws:

`java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates an error at the Registry, possibly a security problem. You need to run the Registry with some debugging parameters to see what, such as -Djava.rmi.server.logCalls etc. See the properties pages linked from the RMI Home Page.

Comment: @kayln12: Also check the `<security>` attribute setting in the `.jnlp` file.

Comment: Security is set to <security> 
<all-permissions/>
</security>

Comment: @EJP thanks for the logging property - the actual exception is due to the behaviour of our own code but was revealed in the logs.